# Is vendor prefixes a temporary addition Or it cover the gab between css levels Now and in future

Tags: css

There are a lot of **vendor prefixes** that try to make **cross browsers compatibility** between the old and new versions ...

my question is it temporary until all old browsers disappear or updated and then no need for it ?

Or we can depend on it when a new level of css shipping to cover maybe the gab between supported and unsupported browsers again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a long answer here, i'll try the short one first.

The vendor tags are a tryhard to avoid glitches or the no-rendering of some properties/attributes. If you need to support an old browser that is obsolete and **unsupported** you may need those vendor tags. If you are working on browsers **with support**, when they are updated, this vendor tags will not be necessary anymore.

Are there any update timeline to know when and when not a vendor tag is needed? **No**

Can we check if some vendor tag is needed on some property? **Yes, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)**, if you want to support a browser that is not capable to run some property, try adding vendor tag.

Remember that vendor tag is not a magician, and it can't render things, the capability of the render engine dealing with vendor tags is different on all versions of the same browser, so i recommend you to check if it really works.

Looking to a *realistic* future, vendor tags will keep working as they worked till nowadays, giving mostly cross-browser compatibility between older and newer versions.

Historically, vendors have also used prefixes for experimental APIs. If an entire interface is experimental, then the interface's name is prefixed (but not the properties or methods within). If an experimental property or method is added to a standardized interface, then the individual method or property is prefixed.

```
Interface prefixes
Prefixes for interface names are upper-cased:

WebKit (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS browsers (including Firefox for iOS); basically, any WebKit based browser)
Moz (Firefox)
O (Older, pre-WebKit, versions of Opera)
MS (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge)


 Property and method prefixes
    The prefixes for properties and methods are lower-case:

webkit (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS browsers (including Firefox for iOS); basically, any WebKit based browser)
moz (Firefox)
o (Old, pre-WebKit, versions of Opera)
ms (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge)
```

Remember that saying "experimental" is subjective, for example, background-size was experimental on I.E. 8, Chrome 3 and FF 3 but it had native support on versions 9, 4 and 4 respectivelly.

Now, to answer your questions with the info: 
Vendor prefixes **are made to be temporary** (till browsers support the feature you're prefixing), **but you'll need to** add vendor prefixes to new "experimental" features if you want to use it, so yes, you'll need vendor prefixes in a future, but to add cross browser compatibility on different properties etc.